# Minimize series limit

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, number-theory, optimization

For a sequence $\{a_n\}$ of non-negative reals that are monotonically increasing, we want to minimize the following two expressions:

$$\sup_k\left(\frac{1}{a_{k-1}}\sum_{n=0}^ka_n\right)$$

$$\lim_{k\to\infty}\left(\frac{1}{a_{k-1}}\sum_{n=0}^ka_n\right)$$

Among sequences of the form $a_n=b^n$, we can explicitly compute the expression: $$\frac{1}{b^{k-1}}\sum_{n=0}^kb^n=\frac{1}{b^{k-1}}\frac{b^{k+1}-1}{b-1}\to\frac{b^2}{b-1}$$ which is minimized for $b=2$, so $a_n=2^n$ minimizes both the supremum and limit expressions.

I suspect $2^n$ achieves the minimum possible value for both expressions.  How could this be proven? Or how could I construct a sequence which achieves a lower value?

Comment: Nice problem.  You can prove it if you consider an arbitrary sequence $\{a_n\}_{n=0}^{\infty}$ of positive non-decreasing numbers and define $\alpha = \limsup_{i\rightarrow\infty} a_{i}/a_{i-1}$ and $\beta = \liminf_{i\rightarrow\infty} a_i/a_{i-1}$.  Then $1\leq \beta \leq \alpha$, and write an "approximate" lower bound on $\frac{1}{a_{k-1}}\sum_{n=0}^k a_n$ for those (suitably large) $k$ indices for which $a_{k}/a_{k-1} \approx \alpha$.

Comment: Isn't a lower bound of $2$ trivial, as $$\frac{1}{a_{k-1}}\sum_{n=0}^k a_n  =  \frac{1}{a_{k-1}} a_k + \frac{1}{a_{k-1}} a_{k-1} + \frac{1}{a_{k-1}}\sum_{n=0}^{k-2} a_n \geq \frac{1}{a_{k-1}} a_k + \frac{1}{a_{k-1}} a_{k-1} \geq 1+1=2$$ using the facts that $a_n\geq0$ and that $a_k\geq a_{k-1}$?

Comment: @ClementC. : Yes, that lower bound value 2 is trivial, but the asker is saying the _factor_ is $b=2$, meaning that the value is $b^2/(b-1)=4$.  So the goal is to prove that the real lower bound is 4.

Comment: @ClementC. If we let $a_k = 2^k$ then we get the ratio of $\frac{2^{k+1}-1}{2^{k-1}} \approx 4$, not $2$. So we must show that $4$ is the lower bound, not $2$.

Comment: @Michael Indeed, I completely missed that "detail."

Comment: @Michael How should i use $\alpha$ and $\beta$ too lower bound that expression?  Do I distribute $1/a_{k-1}$?

Comment: For example, $\frac{1}{a_{k-1}}[a_0+...+a_k]\approx [stuff] + 1 + \alpha \geq ...$.

Comment: I see, I can rewrite it as $\frac{1}{a_{k}}\sum_{n=0}^{k-1}a_n+\frac{a_{k+1}}{a_k}+1$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This answer just clarifies my previous comment (since there is no need to consider $\beta$ as in my first comment):

Consider a general sequence of positive nondecreasing numbers $\{a_n\}_{n=0}^{\infty}$.  Define 
$$\alpha = \limsup_{i\rightarrow\infty} a_{i}/a_{i-1}$$

So $1\leq \alpha \leq \infty$.  You can remove the case $\alpha = \infty$ since then $\sup_k \frac{1}{a_{k-1}}\sum_{n=0}^k a_n = \infty$.  Now for all suitably large $i$ we have that the ratio $a_i/a_{i-1}$ is "approximately" at most $\alpha$ (meaning the ratio is no more than $\alpha + \epsilon$ for any desired $\epsilon>0$).  So for suitably large indices $k$ for which $a_k/a_{k-1} \approx \alpha$ we get

$$ \frac{1}{a_{k-1}}[a_0+...+a_{k-2} + a_{k-1} + a_k] \approx  [stuff] + 1 + \alpha \geq ...$$

Comment: How does this show the lower bound of $4$ ?

Comment: You need to figure out a bound on "stuff" (in terms of $\alpha$).

Comment: It seems like we use $\frac{1}{\alpha}\leq a_{k-1}/a_k$ so we have $\alpha/(\alpha-1)$ is a lower bound on stuff using a geometric series

Comment: But in order for the geometric series to be a lower bound, we need $\alpha$ to be the sup of the ratio, not the lim sup right? because we need the bound on every term?  Conversely, we need it to be the lim sup to be an approximate lower bound on $a_{k}/a_{k-1}$

Comment: Fix $m$ as any positive number, fix $\epsilon>0$. We know we can find arbitrarily large positive integers $k$ such that $a_i/a_{i-1} \leq \alpha+\epsilon$ for all $i \in \{k-m, ..., k\}$

Answer (score 2):

This is too long for a comment but the poster and I have "heuristically" shown that $a_k = 2^k$ must be optimal. I am not sure if the details are correct but hopefully someone can comment on it ?

We can simplify our expression as 
$$ \frac{1}{a_{k-1}} \sum_{n=0}^{k} a_n = \frac{1}{a_{k-1}} \sum_{n=0}^{k-2} a_n + 1 + \frac{a_{k+1}}{a_k}.$$
If 
$$\lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} \frac{a_{k+1}}{a_k} \rightarrow L < \infty,$$
where $L > 1$ then we know that $a_k$ is $\sim CL^{k}$ for some constant $C$. The original poster has already posted an argument that if $a_k$ is geometric, then powers of $2$ are optimal.
Otherwise, if the ratio above converges, we must have 
$$\lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} \frac{a_{k+1}}{a_k} \rightarrow 1.$$
In this case, for $k$, we get that 
$$ \sum_{n=0}^k a_n = O(k) \cdot a_k \implies \frac{1}{a_k} \sum_{n=0}^k a_n = O(k).$$
Therefore, the original expression must diverge. Thus, powers of $2$ are optimal. However, as pointed out in the comments, the argument does not hold if the ratio does not converge.

Comment: *"since $a_k$ is monotonically increasing, we must have"* Why? consider for instance $a_{2n+1} = 2a_{2n}$, $a_{2n+2} = a_{2n+1}+1$ (i.e., the ratio need not converge)

Comment: @ClementC. I see, so if the ratio converges then the argument should hold. Otherwise, we need to be more careful.